# Getting highest and lowest value from a dynamic cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to get the highest and lowest value from cell R1 & R2 in cell AO1 to AP2. I am able to get the highest value in AO1 & AO2 but it does not register the lowest value in AP1 & AP2. The lowest value starts registering once the equivalent numbers (values of R1 & R2) are fed in AP1 & AP2, When trying to Debug, the values in R1 and R2 shows but AP1 and AP2 are "empty".

Can someone help. This is what I have got so far.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'Highest Value

 Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = Range("R1")
 Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = Range("R2")

'Lowest Value

Dim r1a As Range: Set r1a = Range("R1")
Dim r2a As Range: Set r2a = Range("R2")

Application.EnableEvents = False

'This registers the highest value

    If r1.Value > ao1.Value Then
       ao1.Value = r1.Value
    End If
        
    If r2.Value > ao2.Value Then
       ao2.Value = r2.Value
    End If

   'This registers the lowest value

    If r1a.Value < ap1.Value Then
    ap1.Value = r1a.Value
    End If
    
    If r2a.Value < ap2.Value Then
    ap2.Value = r2a.Value
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: you've set max and min to same ranges. Was that intentional? i.e. r1 = r1A and r2=r2A

Comment: Yes that was intentional, was trying a workaround, i suppose r1 & r2 and r1a & r2a does the same job. R1 and R2 will have dynamic values which changes and i need to get the highest value and lowest value from both these cells